# How to pass DateTime parameter in UriTemplate?

Tags: wcf, rest

I want to know how to pass a DateTime parameter(i.e datatype=DateTime) in UriTemplate and also in
    Url when creatin REST services ?
    example :if I want to pass date as 9/17/2012 in UriTemplate and serviceUrl then how to do it?

Comment: [This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412172.aspx) lists the supported (string) formats for DateTime parameters. What else do you need to know? Were are you having (specific) issues?

Answer (score 1):

The only date format that I was able to use successfully, is the Unix Epoch format.
For example, to send `31Dec2012 05:00:00`, I would send `1356930000000`

If you are using javascript this is the value we get from `getTime()` function of a date variable:

```
var milliseconds = (new Date).getTime();
```

WCF web service accepts this value and converts successfully to datetime.